# Mysql select query with count of unique field values

Tags: mysql

There is my query to get contacts from the database:

```
$contacts = $dbh->prepare("
SELECT r.title region_title
     , c.title
     , c.region_id
     , c.id
     , c.catalog_id
     , c.address
     , c.phone
     , c.email
     , c.website
     , c.category_title
     , c.subcategory_title
     , c.subcategory_id
     , c.manufacturer 
  FROM contacts c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN regions r 
    ON c.region_id = r.id 
 WHERE manufacturer = 1 
   AND region_id IN (".implode(',', $regions).") 
   AND subcategory_id IN (".implode(',', $categories).")
");
```

And getting a list of contacts grouping buy region_title

```
$contacts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP)
```

Result is:

```
array() {
  ["First region title"]=>
  array() {
    contact1
    contact2
    ...
  },
  ["Second region title"]=>
  array() {
    contact3
    contact4
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I get the number of unique c.catalog_id fields in the same query?

Comment: Can you let us know what output you have in mind?

Comment: I need a list of contacts and number of contacts with unique c.catalog_id value (that will be less than contacts list length)

Comment: As an aside, note that are some clever scripts out there demonstrating how IN can securely be used conjunction with prepare.

Comment: And I forgot to say about FETCH_GROUP

Answer (score 0):

You can get unique catalog_id fields by groupping by catalog_id and set having condition as below:

```
$contacts = $dbh->prepare("
SELECT r.title region_title
 , c.title
 , c.region_id
 , c.id
 , c.catalog_id
 , c.address
 , c.phone
 , c.email
 , c.website
 , c.category_title
 , c.subcategory_title
 , c.subcategory_id
 , c.manufacturer 
 FROM contacts c 
LEFT 
  JOIN regions r 
ON c.region_id = r.id 
 WHERE manufacturer = 1 
 AND region_id IN (".implode(',', $regions).") 
 AND subcategory_id IN (".implode(',', $categories).")
 GROUP BY catalog_id HAVING COUNT(catalog_id)=1
");
```

Comment: `"error":["42000",1055,"Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'basename.r.title' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"]`